# Use PDF editor for book publishing (including conversion to PDF/X)

Tags: pdf, file-conversion, publishing, affinity-publisher

I know that there is dedicated software for book publishing, such as Affinity Publisher, Adobe Indesign, and so on, but I have used for a certain project LaTeX, which would produce a PDF.

Since most of the typography is taken care of in LaTeX, I am interested in possibly doing some finishing touches in a PDF editor. These touches could be simple removal or simple additions of elements, and at least and necessarily conversion of the PDF to PDF/X-1a:2001 or PDF/X-3:2002. (They could also include greater acts, if I'd fancy it, such as realigning page margins.)

I don't use Adobe (nor they me), and I will need a PDF editor.

**So, in this case, if one does not use Adobe software, needs the said conversion (or export), and wants to do some light (or heavier) PDF editing, is it good and a safe choice to go for a dedicated professional non-Adobe PDF editor?**

**Extra information or subquestions possibly relevant or important:**

- Of course I would want the resulting end PDF/X to comply to the standard properly, and I am also interested in knowing about the *resulting visual quality*. If a well-known trusted company existing and serving for a long time states they have PDF/X compliance, then chances are this is true. But should one use it for book publishing and PDF conversion at all?
- Should I just import my PDF in Affinity Publisher, do my edits there, and then use a dedicated professional PDF editor to convert to PDF/X-1a:2001 or PDF/X3:2002 (as Aff. Publisher doesn't have these two options (and I even read that their PDF/X conversion wasn't that good, though I don't know that last one for sure))?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do these final touches in the PDF itself, rather than in the LaTeX document when exporting to PDF?

Comment: To save time, and in any case I would need to convert to a certain version of PDF/X, which most likely is a problem in LaTeX at the moment. I considered using ConTeXt, but this would take too much time too (to migrate the project). May as well investigate concerning a dedicated PDF editor, and possibly go for it, if suitable.